# Is $-\frac47$ a proper fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I was asked this question by a kid:

> Is $- \frac{4}{7}$ a proper fraction or not?

As per my knowledge, $\frac{4}{7}$ is a proper fraction. If it has a negative number, does it make any difference?

Definition says:

> A number whose numerator is smaller than denominator is called a proper fraction.

Can we consider $- \frac{4}{7}$as a proper fraction? If not, why? Please explain.

**EDIT:** I have got these links from comments [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Proper_and_improper_common_fractions) and a link form [math world](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperFraction.html) and both contradicting each other.

Thank you.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperFraction.html So it's neither proper or improper.

Comment: It is proper: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Proper_and_improper_common_fractions

Comment: If I had to define a convention that makes sense in the context of where questions like this have relevance, I would say that `-4/7` isn't a fraction at all; it is a numeral consisting of a negative sign `-` and a (proper) fraction `4/7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Proper_and_improper_common_fractions):

> Common fractions can be classified as either proper or improper. When the numerator and the denominator are both positive, the fraction is called proper if the numerator is less than the denominator, and improper otherwise. In general, a common fraction is said to be a *proper fraction* if the absolute value of the fraction is strictly less than one—that is, if the fraction is between $-1$ and $1$.* [Italics mine]

So $\;-1 < \left(-\dfrac 47\right) < 1$ is considered a *proper fraction*; (alternatively $\;\;0 < \Big|-\dfrac 47 \Big| = \dfrac 47 < 1$.

---

I think in terms of mathworld's definition: When using the division algorithm, for example, one requires an integer quotient $\times$ an integer divisor, plus a non-negative integer remainder less than the value of the divisor. So if dividing $-4$ by $7$:

$$-4 = -1\cdot 7 + 3, \;\;q = -1;\;\;r = 3, i.e., -\dfrac 47 = -1 + \dfrac 37$$ which would be a *mixed fraction*.

So the fractional part would be the proper fraction $\dfrac 37$, the integer part, $-1$. Consistent with this, mathworld may require that a proper fraction occurs only when the quotient is $0$, and the remainder a positive integer less than the divisor, hence the fractional part = $\dfrac rd\; d: $divisor,$\;r: $ the remainder when dividing number by $d$.

Comment: I have edited my question added a link form mathworld given by Lazar in the comment. This is confusing. Which one is correct?

Comment: It's a matter of convention - By any other name, it'd still smell the same.

Comment: The Wikipedia definition is the standard. I think mathworld left out the clause that the $0 < $ |fraction|$ < 1$

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the fraction remains the same even if it's positive or negatively signed. Because sign is usually a measure of direction rather than quantity. Hence -(proper fraction) remains a proper fraction, because the actual ratio of the quantities is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but in my humble opinion, $-\frac{4}{7}$ is not even a fraction: a fraction is a division of two integer numbers, but $-\frac{4}{7}$ is not a fraction, but the negation of a fraction (where by "negation" I mean the result of the multiplication by $-1$).

Kid : But what about $\frac{-4}{7}$ or $\frac{4}{-7}$?
I : Well, those are actual fractions, but none of them is a proper fraction, as at least one of them is not positive.

Kid : And what about $\frac{4}{7}$, from which $-\frac{4}{7}$ is the negation?
I : Well, that one is also a fraction, and even a proper one, as both members (nominator and denominator) are positive.

Kid : But what about $\frac{-4}{-7}$? It's equal to $\frac{4}{7}$, so it should also be a proper fraction, isn't it?
I : Well: no! $\frac{4}{7}$ is a fraction, and even a proper one. $\frac{-4}{-7}$ is also a fraction, but not a proper one: the fact that it's value is equal to a proper fraction, does not make it a proper fraction itself.

Kid : That makes no sense: the values are equal but one is a proper fraction and the other not, that's nonsense!
I : You think so? Tell me: $\frac{1}{10}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{6}$ are all fractions, because they consist of a nominator, divided by a denominator, isn't it?
Kid : Yes, that's the definition of a fraction.
I : ... and numbers, like $1$, $2$ and $3$ are just natural numbers and not fractions, right?
Kid : Yes, indeed.
I : What about $\frac{1}{1}$, $\frac{2}{1}$ and $\frac{6}{2}$? Although their values are $1$, $2$ and $3$, they should be natural numbers, but yet they are written as divisions of natural numbers and hence, they are fractions, right?
Kid : Yes, that seems to be right. But tell me: why do adults make things so difficult for a kid?
I : For a kid? I'm an adult with a degree in mathematics, and even I find this difficult, so for you: you can say that it's too difficult for you as a kid, or your can be proud understanding something that even adults are struggling with. What's your choice? :-)